# Manga where reborn Demon lord searches for his former companions

Tags: story-identification, manga

This was a manga about a demon lord(?) reborn in the future. He is searching for his past comrades.

I recall two of them. One is like a robot/android girl and another one is a giant rainbow sheep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is '*[A Wild Last Boss Appeared!](https://mywaifulist.moe/series/a-wild-last-boss-appeared-manga)*'.

> The year is 2800 and Lufas Maphaahl – The Black-Winged Tyrant, Great Conqueror, and leader of the Twelve Heavenly Stars – has returned. A man wakes up in the body of his MMO character 200 years after her defeat during an player-made event in the game, Exgate Online. Now, he's stuck in her body. But this isn’t a game, it’s real. With her reign long over, and her legacy one of fear, Lufas must journey through the world of Exgate, looking for answers, possible comrades, and all the monsters her “death” unleashed upon the world...

The Tyrant's companion is Aries, a gigantic rainbow-coloured sheep that sometimes takes the form of a scantily clad young girl.

> Aries is a unique monster from the species "Rainbow Sheep", he was tamed when he was a weak monster by the Overlord Ruphas Mafahl.
> After that, he trained and his weakness became his strength. Later, when the Overlord Ruphas Mafahl created The Twelve Heavenly Stars, his strength was proved and he became part of it.

Comment: yes that the one must have confused it with "I, the Strongest Demon, Have Regained My Youth?" becaus its similar but thats the right one thanks